# LongListSelector spacing between items

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, spacing, longlistselector

I have a LongListSelector which is populated with some items. Each item has a submenu which can be visible or collapsed using a sliding animation. The problem is the spacing between the items, which should be 0. But when I use the sliding animation a couple of times, the spacing is sometimes a few pixels. When you scroll way down and back up the list will rerender and the spacing is gone.

Here are some screenshots, don't mind the ugly colours, I used them to keep the different elements apart from eachother. Purple is background color if the longlistselector. Each item has a red 1px border.

This is how it should be:

[image: good]

And when I clicked the show/hide button a few times:

[image: bad2]

And here is my code:

LongListSelector:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LongList" Margin="0" Padding="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="DarkOrchid">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>     

                    <!-- 1st ROW -->
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" Background="DarkKhaki" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">                            
                        <Grid>                               
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

                            <TextBlock Text="Test Item" FontSize="42" />
                            <Button Content="v" Grid.Column="1" Tap="Button_Tap" Tag="{Binding}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SubMenuIsVisible}" Value="True">
                                        <eim:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play">
                                            <eim:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)"
                                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="Submenu"
                                                                     From="0" To="60" Duration="0:0:0.25" />

                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Submenu"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Visibility)">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                                                        

                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </eim:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                                        </eim:ControlStoryboardAction>
                                    </ec:DataTrigger>

                                    <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SubMenuIsVisible}" Value="False">
                                        <eim:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play">
                                            <eim:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)"
                                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="Submenu"
                                                                     From="60" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />

                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Submenu"
                                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Visibility)">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </eim:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                                        </eim:ControlStoryboardAction>
                                    </ec:DataTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>                                    
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <!-- SUB Menu -->
                    <Border x:Name="Submenu" Grid.Row="1" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="SubMenu" FontSize="42" />
                    </Border>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

**EDIT:**
I suspect this problem has something to do with performance issues. I posted a new question for this, you can find it here:

[Slow storyboard animation inside LongListSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070792/slow-storyboard-animation-inside-longlistselector)

Answer (score 0):

The LongListSelector likes putting arbitrary padding/margins/overlap on stuff without any actual reason. I've found that using a ListBox is typically a more stable and less headachey-prone solution.

I can't see an obvious solution except maybe trying a `StackPanel` instead of a Grid with an Auto height.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, a StackPanel makes no difference. I think found the problem though. The animation is causing some major performance issues depending on where you tap in the list. I'm not sure yet why it does.